# How to align element inside a nested Row in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, row

Here is my code, now I wanted to align the two icons(copy and favorite) in the right bottom in the same row of that the author name. I don't want to use padding here because that will create a problem as the author's name is of different lengths.
Thanks in advance...[image: as shown in the image the blue lines are indicating where I want to align the two icons, hope you get a clear image]

```
SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 2, 8, 1),
                child: Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.90,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      gradient: LinearGradient(
                          colors: <Color>[
                            Colors.blue,
                            Colors.yellow,
                          ]
                      )
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Text(
                          Show_It[index].quote.toString(),
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 17,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            Show_It[index].author.toString(),
                          ),
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              IconButton(
                                onPressed: () async{
                                  FlutterClipboard.copy(Show_It[index].quote.toString()).then((value) => {
                                    Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Copied to clipboard")
                                  });
                                },
                                icon: Icon(
                                  Icons.copy,
                                ),
                              ),
                              Material(
                                color: Colors.transparent,
                                child: IconButton(
                                  onPressed: () async{
                                    CollectionReference ref= FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                        .collection("users")
                                        .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
                                        .collection('Favourites');
                                    var data={
                                      'Quote': Show_It[index].quote,
                                      'author': Show_It[index].author,
                                    };
                                    ref.add(data).then((value) => {
                                      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Added to Favourites")
                                    });
                                  },
                                  splashRadius: 20,
                                  splashColor: Colors.redAccent,
                                  icon: Icon(
                                    Icons.favorite,
                                    color: Colors.red,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          )
                        ],
                      ),

                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
```

I hope I mentioned all the necessary details , ignore the extra code if it's there, that is already in use

Answer (score 0):

On First `Row` widget set `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,`

```dart
child: Column(
  children: [
    //..
    Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        Text(
          Show_It[index].author.toString(),
        ),
        Row(
```

you can also include [`Spacer()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Spacer-class.html) but It is not necessary to include extra widget

```dart
children: [
  //..
  Row(
    children: [
      Text("X"),
      Spacer(),
      Row(
```

More about [Row](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Row-class.html) and [layout](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout)